# TFS Group Membership - HTTP code 400: Bad Request

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I am working with a new installation of TFS2012 and after working within a project collection for a bit I went into the Admin Console to change the group membership. Clicking on the Group Membership or Administer Security links within the Admin Console results in an error:

> The request was rejected by the server. HTTP code 400: Bad Request

I've verified and reapplied both the service account permissions and the Admin Console Users permissions with no luck. I can, however, configure the security via the web based control panel for the collection.

Anyone have ideas of the possible cause?

Comment: Like with all HTTP problems install Wireshark and have a look what runs wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

apparently TFS is real pick on which IIS bindings are configured. By reverting to the default "*" bindings instead of a specific host header I was able to get all the security buttons to work.

Now I have two bindings for the tfs website in iis.

1st: *:8080
2nd: tfs.company.com:8080

Answer (score 0):

I added a http binding to * and port 8080 in IIS and it resolved this problem along with similar issues related to managing team projects and collections.